# How to Insert in SQL Database and Update some records in another Database in different server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

There are 2 different database in 2 different SQL Server, so there are 2 connection string.

I want to have a trigger that if a record has been inserted in database1, some fields will update in database2.

for example:

Database1:

```
ServerIP : x.x.x.x
ServerPort : 1433
Username : x1
password : x2
```

Database2:

```
ServerIP : y.y.y.y
ServerPort : 1590
Username : y1
Password : y2
```

[image]

so how can I write a trigger or any other things for this purpose?

Comment: My bad. I suppose you could create a linked server and trigger?

Comment: I can just connect to the second server, what u mean by linked server?

Comment: Refer to this MSDN link on Linked Servers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx Basically you link the other server, and then you can access it from within queries on your first server.

Comment: Please look at the picture that I have attached in my question. I have lined server, but I cant access both of them in same time in queries

Comment: Can't chat, but are you sure that is a linked server and not just a separate connection? I've fixed the MSDN link, please check

Comment: Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. If you're happy with the below, please vote answer, thanks.

```
            CREATE TABLE dbo.TestData (
            ServerIP VARCHAR(20),
            ServerPort SMALLINT,
            Username VARCHAR(100),
            [Password] VARCHAR(100)
            );

            GO

            -- Table created on other server/instance after you set up linked server
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestData2] (
            ServerIP VARCHAR(20),
            ServerPort SMALLINT,
            Username VARCHAR(100),
            [Password] VARCHAR(100)
            );

            GO

            -------- Insert trigger ------
            CREATE TRIGGER dbo.AI_InsertConnectionInfo ON [dbo].[TestData]
            AFTER INSERT
            AS


              INSERT INTO [YourServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[TestData2] (ServerIP, ServerPort, Username, [Password])
              SELECT I.ServerIP
                    ,I.ServerPort
                    ,I.UserName
                    ,I.[Password]
              FROM dbo.TestData AS T
              INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON T.ServerIP = I.ServerIP;

            GO

            INSERT INTO dbo.TestData
            VALUES ('192.168.1.1', 1433, 'TestUserName', 'Test123');

            GO

            -- Connect to your new server and query the table to confirm the data's there.

            SELECT * 
            FROM dbo.TestData2;



            -------- Update trigger -------

            CREATE TRIGGER dbo.AU_UpdateConnectionInfo ON [dbo].[TestData]
            AFTER UPDATE
            AS


              UPDATE T
              SET    T.ServerIP = I.ServerIP
                    ,T.ServerPort = I.ServerPort
                    ,T.UserName = I.UserName
                    ,T.[Password] = I.[Password]
              FROM [YourServerName].[DatabaseName].[dbo].[TestData2]  AS T
              INNER JOIN inserted AS I ON T.ServerIP = I.ServerIP;
```